Is there a name for functions with two unique outputs?
Euclidean division is a function from $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}^+$ to $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$
$$\div:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}^+\to\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$$
Each dividend $a$ and divisor $b$ are mapped to TWO unique values, a quotient $q$ and a remainder $r$.
$$a\div b=q\text{R}r=\langle q,r\rangle$$
$q$ and $r$ are not necessarily interchangeable because each value serves its own purpose in Euclid's division lemma.
$$\forall a\in\mathbb{N}\forall b\in\mathbb{N}^+\exists!q,r\in\mathbb{N}\\(r<b\land a=b\times q+r)$$
Where
$$\exists!x,y\Phi(x,y)$$
is equivalent to:
$$\exists!x\exists y\Phi(x,y)\land\exists!y\exists x\Phi(x,y)$$
which is equivalent to:
$$\exists x,y(\Phi(x,y)\land\nexists a,b(\Phi(a,b)\land(a\neq x\lor b\neq y)))$$
Point being, there are two unique values that are not (necessarily) interchangeable.
Is there a name for such a function?

The output is the unique pair $\langle q, r\rangle$.   It's just a usual function between those two sets.  It happens to be surjective, not but not injective.

I know it's just a function, in the same sense that a binary operation is just a function and a function is a just a relation.  I was just wondering if there was more to it or are these kinds of functions not talked about.

These kinds of functions aren't really talked about unless you can find something special about them.  Then you have a theorem.   GCD is still very mysterious to us, in the sense that you can write a two-line program in SymPy that does a single GCD test (the while-loop condition).  If you can prove that such a program always terminates, then you've proven twin primes.  In that sense, we don't really understand it yet!  (digression)

Thanks. I'm just gonna write in my notes a function with a "binary value" until someone comes up with a better name for it.

Or "natural number pair-valued" function.  Whatever rolls off the tongue nicely will work just fine :)  But also note the way you have described, 99% of mathematicians will already know precisely what you mean.   By that I mean your symbols in your definition work great.

Pair-valued sounds nice too. I think this description is noteworthy as well!

FWIW, a pair-valued function has the same mathematical data as a pair of (scalar-valued) functions. The significance of bundling things one way or the other is more of a computer programming issue.

In the usual mathematical notation, a function only has one output. However, that one output may comprise a pair of values (or a triple, or an $n$-tuple for any $n$). It is traditional to think of a function that takes a pair as an input as a function of two arguments, but we don't usually think about a single function as having two outputs, even though, as you point out, algorithms like Euclidean division often do produce what we might think of as two outputs. You can think of the Euclidean division algorithm either as a single function $(a, b) \mapsto (a \div b, a \mathop{\mathrm{mod}} b)$ that outputs a pair or as the two functions $\div$ and $\mathrm{mod}$.
So the name for "a function with two outputs" is "a function whose value range over pairs". But it is clearer to use $\to$ and $\times$ to be more precise about what the inputs and outputs of your functions are. E.g., in your example, you could say "the Euclidean division algorithm defines a function $(\Bbb{N}\times \Bbb{N}) \to (\Bbb{N}\times \Bbb{N})$".

This can be called a vector function or vector-valued function. The output of the function is not a scalar number, but a vector of numbers.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-valued_function

Vectors usually imply you're in a module or vector space.  Would have to extend codomain to all of $\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$, etc.  I didn't downvote! :)

I feel this is more for vector spaces but thanks still. However I didn't notice until you wrote this that both are mappings to ordered pairs, just under very different contexts.

@DanielDonnelly Vector spaces are, by definition, over fields. You would have to extend to at least $\Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q$. Modules are in general not vector spaces, and elements of modules are similarly not vectors.

@Arthur, or modulo everything by a prime $q$ lol!
